# Why does Jest throw when an error when toBe fails?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

This is for Jest 28.1.1. You can see the problem when doing the example demo with sum(); this is with TypeScript so ts-jest (v28.0.4) is also involved if that makes a difference.

```
// x.ts
export function sum(a :number, b :number) :number {
    return a + b;
}
```

Then the tests/x.test.ts is

```
import * as x from "../x";

describe("app tests", () => {
    test('app function1 function', () => {
        expect(x.sum(2,2)).toBe(4);
        try {    // test for throw
            expect(x.sum(2,2)).toBe(5); // should fail
        } catch (error:any) {
            console.log("===============catch: " + error + "===============");
        }
        expect(x.sum(2,2)).toBe(6); // should fail
        expect(x.sum(2,2)).toBe(7); // should fail
    });
});
```

The reason for the test to begin with was to verify it would show multiple failures, but it will only show the first. Eventually I added the try/catch just to see if there was a throw I was unaware of and I found it was happening! When I run "npm test" (which runs "jest --coverage" from my package.json) I get:

```
console.log
  ===============catch: Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

  Expected: 5
  Received: 4===============

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/data/tests/x.test.ts:10:21)
```

Why is toBe() throwing an error? My code is not doing the throw.
How do I make it not do that? Is there a configuration affecting this I haven't found"

I want it to show me 1 pass and 3 fails, but a throw from somewhere is preventing that and I can't find anything about this in the docs or in the github issues.

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save-dev jest (do this)
and
npm install jest --global (do this)

npm install --save-dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env ( i dont do this )

i using babel in my VSCode, but do not install babel and set babel in babel.config.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).